# Storing Email Body in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, email, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys I am building a bulk email sending application for my client and right now I am designing the database architecture. Basically there will be hundreds of thousands emails per day and I need to store them in database.

What will be the best way to store the email's body in database? Do I store them in `varchar(max)` column, or do I save them in file system and save their path in the database? Or is there any other approach to this? I am only worried about performance of the application. Btw I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Isn't most bulk email just variations on a template? Why save all the messages?

Comment: Well the names among other things will be customized for each email, so that is why I need to save all emails.

Comment: Can't you recrate mail bodies afterwards, based on (unchanged) template and few variable fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I don't recommend building bulk email sending activities as there are a lot things to be done to avoid [considering your email as spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

However if you decided to do it your self you need to decide the content of the emails, Is it text only, HTML that may contains embedded images,...

You can use `varchar(max)` for the field type. performance will not be a big issue however consider thinking about the retention policies

if you would like to save the email as file then you can use FILESTREAM which will provide you with better performance given that you use the SqlFileStream APIs

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SQL Server 2008 I use Mysql that it has BLOB or TEXT column.

I think that also SQL Server has this type of fields. Into a LONGBLOB field you can store about L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32.

Besides, you can store also any attached files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `varchar(max)` as it will be the easiest option to keep all data in the database so you can migrate, replicate or whatever the database and everything will be kept intact. Storing part of the data outside the database will only complicate things without any gain.

Performance on the data part will not be a problem, you will have bigger problem getting the spam^H^H^H^H emails delivered out of your box.

Just think about data cleanup from the beginning, as storing each and every email separately will over time use a bit of diskspace. With suitable indexes the amount of data should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably not to do it :) You need to find out from the client precisely why they want to do this. More often than not people store bulk data like this because they think they should, then never ever look at it. If you need to store this data, for how long, and what's the archiving process going to be? As mentioned elsewhere storing a pointer to a template then the inserted values would be a much more compact way of doing this, but again, only do it if you really need to. Storing the emails as files in a file system isn't a crazy idea, but avoid directories with thousands of files in.

Something else to consider for large databases is the disaster recovery strategy - how long will it take to backup every night, how long to restore in a DR scenario. How many backups are you going to keep, online & offline, and how much space do you need for that? In this regard, having 'application data' and 'archived data' in seperate databases might be a good starting point.

From a technical SQL Server perspective there are things that could help such as table partitioning and data compression, but understanding the requirement is still the most important place to start.